# How to deactivate chrono set in batch with WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I have activated 3200 chronos in total which I'd like to deactivate as the server can't handle it.

Where should I go to deactivate these on the database or with a function that might deactivate this or what would the right direction be.

This was the kind of activation I did in batch:

```
if(!wp_next_scheduled('myfunc_global_update_h1')){
wp_schedule_event(time(),'hourly','myfunc_global_update_h1');
}
add_action('myfunc_global_update_h1','myfunc_global_update1');
```

and there is that function also myfunc_global_update1

now the functions will be deleted from the file in which those events got registered, scheduled however it is it works.

But will that be enough ? I don't know how this all works too well.

All of the information I find is related to setting the chronos, but not unsetting.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is [`wp_cron`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) and related functions, not "chrono" which is a C# library (I think).

I believe that what you need is [`wp_clear_scheduled_hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_clear_scheduled_hook) which "Un-schedules all previously-scheduled cron jobs using a particular hook name."

```
wp_clear_scheduled_hook('myfunc_global_update_h1');
```